# using switches to find the largest of 3 variables

Tags: c++

My teacher just showed us `switch`. I have the program that we used in the class for a demonstration and he doesn't want us to change anything except the last line where the switch is.

This is the line we have to change

```
cout << ("the greatest between " << val1 << ", " << val2 << " and " << val3 << " is " << ((((val1 > val2) ? val1 : val2) ? : val1 > val2 > val3 : ) << endl;
```

That's the line of code I'm using right now. The program works, but it keeps giving me 0 as the largest, so the problem is the last part is not able to find the largest of the variables that were inputted.

Comment: `val1 > val2 > val3` doesn't do what you think it does.

Comment: This program can't possibly compile. Also, when someone says "program works" they usually imply "works as expected".

Comment: @WhozCraig and [gcc](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/20AsLC) is even kind enough to tell you that.

Comment: how can i fix it i understand the first part which find the largest one out of val1 and val2 but then i don't know how to make it find the larger one from val1, val2 and val3 since i don't know what variable will be taken from the first part

Comment: How would you express the same thing using `if`s and `else`s (or even in plain english)? Start from there.

Comment: That's not a `switch`. It's a ternary operator.

Answer (score 0):

As stated in comments, your code doesn't even compile properly.  So you need to fix that first.  Your second use of `?:` is malformed.

`val1 > val2 > val3` evaluates to a `bool`, which when converted to an integer will be either 1 (`true`) or 0 (`false`).  And any integer evaluated as a boolean will be either `true` (non-zero) or `false` (zero).  So that is why your code ends up outputting 0 (if it compiles at all), because you end up with a `false` result value being converted to an integer.

You would need to use something more like this instead:

```
cout << "the greatest between " << val1 << ", " << val2 << " and " << val3 << " is " << ((val1 > val2) ? ((val1 > val3) ? val1 : val3) : ((val2 > val3) ? val2 : val3)) << endl;
```

But, doing all those comparisons in one statement is not very readable.  You should use a local variable to hold the result of the comparison, then print out the variable, eg:

```
greatest = (val1 > val2)
            ? ((val1 > val3) ? val1 : val3)
            : ((val2 > val3) ? val2 : val3);
cout << "the greatest between " << val1 << ", " << val2 << " and " << val3 << " is " << greatest << endl;
```

Or:

```
greatest = (val1 > val2) ? val1 : val2;
greatest = (greatest > val3) ? greatest : val3;
cout << "the greatest between " << val1 << ", " << val2 << " and " << val3 << " is " << greatest << endl;
```

Now, that being said, using `switch` in this situation does not make sense, and won't really help you.  It would end up looking something like this:

```
switch (val1 > val2)
{
    case true:
        switch (val1 > val3)
        {
            case true:
                greatest = val1;
                break;
           case false:
               greatest = val3;
               break;
        }
        break;
    case false:
        switch (val2 > val3)
        {
            case true:
                greatest = val2;
                break;
           case false:
               greatest = val3;
               break;
        }
        break;
};

cout << "the greatest between " << val1 << ", " << val2 << " and " << val3 << " is " << greatest << endl
```

Or:

```
switch (val1 > val2)
{
    case true:
        greatest = val1;
        break;
    case false:
        greatest = val2;
        break;
}

switch (greatest > val3)
{
    case false:
        greatest = val3;
        break;
}

cout << "the greatest between " << val1 << ", " << val2 << " and " << val3 << " is " << greatest << endl;
```

Which is really no better than using `if`/`else` blocks:

```
if (val1 > val2)
{
    if (val1 > val3)
        greatest = val1;
    else
        greatest = val3;
}
else
{
    if (val2 > val3)
        greatest = val2;
    else
        greatest = val3;
}

cout << "the greatest between " << val1 << ", " << val2 << " and " << val3 << " is " << greatest << endl
```

Or:

```
if (val1 > val2)
    greatest = val1;
else
    greatest = val2;

if (val3 > greatest)
    greatest = val3;

cout << "the greatest between " << val1 << ", " << val2 << " and " << val3 << " is " << greatest << endl;
```

Comment: As a wild guess, I'd say that the `switch` mentioned in the question has nothing to do with the conditional operator. I'd bet on a "menu" like user interaction, where one of the options is to evaluate the maximum, but that's to the OP to clarify.

Comment: ya its not a switch i thought it was my apologies about that i have to use a switch for another program after this one

Comment: Aren't you getting _warning: switch condition has boolean value_ on statement 
`switch (val1 > val2)`?

Comment: @H.S. maybe, I don't know, I didn't compile the code, I just wrote it.

Comment: @marcosangiovanni that kind of information should have been presented up front.  This info fundamentally changes the nature of your question.

Comment: @remylebeau Can’t use a switch for this i have to use the first method you put which I tried but it gives me 0 still when I input the variables

Comment: @marcosangiovanni it returns 0 the way you were originally using it, not the way I have shown it.

Comment: ya it works it was a error from another program im working on for homework that was affecting this program